# Restoring a model with tensorflow does not lead to same prediction

Tags: tensorflow

my question revolves around Tensorflow and its tf.train.Saver() function to save the state of a network and restore afterwards. My code is very long and messy but it is structured as:

- Generate a set of parameter settings for the network
- Build the network
- Either train the network or restore it based on saved model file
- Predict on some external data

Now to my question. When I run my model with the exact same parameters several times I get the exact same performance. If I restore the same model several times I also get the same performance. However, the performance when I train the model and when I restore model are not the same, even if the restored model comes directly from the trained model. I have tried to save either the whole model (so tf.train.Saver() which creates huge files) or just trainable variables (so tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables()) which makes much smaller files) and both give the same result, but it is still not identical to directly training the model. Keep in mind that the differences are generally very small, and for some of the individual tasks in my network they are identical, but the difference bugs me.

I have seen several questions about Tensorflow model saving and restoring but none seem to solve my question. As far as I can see the model restores correctly (I check that the weights were the same and they seem to be) but it doesn't give the exact same results. I think I can rule out random events in my code because while training and restoring I can reproduce the same results given the same parameters. I am not sure how to proceed.

Does any one know why I have this problem?

I add just small snippets of the code below. First how I restore the model:

```
def load_network_state(model_file):

  print('Restoring model')

  # saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables())
  saver = tf.train.Saver()
  sess=tf.Session()
  saver.restore(sess, model_file)
  return sess
```

In the training function:

`# saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables())
 saver = tf.train.Saver()
 if model_file is not None:
        save_path=saver.save(sess, model_file+'_{0}'.format(model_suffix))`

In the main loop:

```
if args['restore_network']:
    params = create_parameters_from_file(args['arg_file'], args, j)
else:
    params=create_random_parameter(args)

start=time.time()
train_data, test_data = transform(train_data, test_data, params)

kwargs=generate_kwargs_dictionary(generate_network, params)
features, targets, predictions, train_op = generate_network(train_data, test_data, model_suffix=j, **kwargs)
if args['restore_network']:
    session = load_network_state(params['model_file']+'_{0}'.format(j), params['seed'])
else:
    kwargs=generate_kwargs_dictionary(network_training, params)
    session = network_training(train_data, features, targets, train_op, model_suffix=j, **kwargs)

kwargs=generate_kwargs_dictionary(network_prediction, params)    
training_results = network_prediction(train_data, features, targets, predictions, session, model_suffix=j, **kwargs)
test_results = network_prediction(test_data, features, targets, predictions, session, model_suffix=j, **kwargs)
elapsed=time.time()-start
```

Thank you for any help you could provide

Comment: maybe you need to initialize your graph before restore your model by using tf.global_variables_initializer()

Comment: Hi @UN2758, thanks for the suggestion. To be honest I stop worrying about this when I noticed that when running my models on the GPU, results were not consistent and apparently that is by design. So, as every important model I will use will be trained in GPU, it makes no sense to worry any more.